# Qual site alternativo a Admob para anucio nos app Android?

Tags: android, admob, publicidade

Bom busco site alternativos `Admob` para colocar publicidade no aplicativos `Android`, gostaria de que vocês indicasse os melhores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo a utilização do [`MoPub`](https://get.fabric.io/mopub?locale=pt-BR) que faz parte do `Fabric` (Twitter).

Sua implementação é super simples, e possui vários tipos de anúncios.

Além disso, [aqui você pode encontrar um ótimo exemplo](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk) de como implementar e conhecer um pouco mais sobre a plataforma

Comment: não estou conseguindo instalar o plugin do `Fabric` esta dando erro, eu fiz um pergunta a respeito http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68799/ajuda-na-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-plugin-a-fabric-mopub

Comment: me da uma ajuda por favor, quando você instala o plugin do mopub você escolhe o tipo de anuncio banner etc, ele te da todo código para você ir colando no lugar certo beleza, ai você executa funciona certinho aparece no anuncio teste, ai você vai no site e cria o banner pega chave e troca a que esta no programa , ai testei no celular físico e anuncio não aparece, tem mais configuração a fazer ?.

Comment: @scachester  se você achar melhor abro uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @Rodolfo crie outra pergunta por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Parceiro, o AdBuddiz tbm fornece serviços de monetização para aplicações mobile.

Confere: http://www.adbuddiz.com/developers

Comment: conhece só este ou existe outros ?

Comment: http://www.inlocomedia.com/publisher?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=lead&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-tSrBRCk8bzDiO__gbwBEiQAk-D31edd8U_5G5gP2q3A1Lmj-x4lUk1i35oFxjNfBcKoZFsaAkK98P8HAQ

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/apis/earn/mobile-associates