# Ajuda na instalação do plugin a Fabric mopub

Tags: android-studio, plugin

Baixei o plugin do site, instalei-o no `Android Studio`, porém dá este erro aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vá em `Arquivo > Invalidar Cache e Reinicializar`

Comment: não  funcionou fera

Comment: baixou deste link? https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio

Comment: sim, exatamente este

Comment: referente os passos do link que você postou, ele da o erro ao reiniciar, mostrando exatamente igual a figura acima.

Comment: Problema resolvido basta acionar o pacote inteiro, eu estava descompactando e tentava instalar ai dava esse erro.